# pyvis graph either overlapping, or not showing labels

Tags: python, pyvis

I'm doing a project where i am drawing a graph from a python repo, my code is really long, and not the important part. But here it is, in case someone wants to try to reporduce:

```
import ast
from radon.visitors import ComplexityVisitor
import re
import os
from pyvis.network import Network


class Vert:
    def __init__(self, name, id, size ,edges):
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
        self.edges = edges
        self.id = id
        
from pathlib import Path

rootDir = "/home/ask/Git/Zeeguu-API/"
directories = set()
# this is horrible
for file in Path(rootDir).rglob("*.py"):
    localDirs = str(file).split('/')
    directories.add(localDirs[-2])


def extract_importandClass_from_line(unline):

    x = re.search("^import (\S+)", unline) 
    x = re.search("^from (\S+)", unline) 
    return x.group(1)#, c.group(1).split('(')[0]
def extractClass(inline):
    c = re.search("^class (\S+)", inline) 
    return c.group(1).split('(')[0]


def importsAndClass(file):
    lines = [line for line in open(file)]
    classes = []
    all_imports = []
    for line in lines:
        try:
            imports = extract_importandClass_from_line(line)
            importEnd = imports.rsplit('.',1)[-1]
            importsFormatted = imports.replace('.', '/')
            if (importEnd not in directories):
                all_imports.append(importsFormatted)
        except:
            try:
                class1 = extractClass(line)
                classes.append(class1)
            except:
                continue  
  
    return all_imports, classes
net = Network(directed=True, height="1500px", width="100%")
nodes = {}
nodeNames = set()
counter = 0
for file in Path(rootDir).rglob("*.py"):
    # Opening file, and looking at contents
    f = open(file, "r")
    s = f.read()
    # analyzing complexity
    filename = str(file).replace(rootDir, "")
    analyzer = ComplexityVisitor.from_code(s)
    
    # getting the file name 
    splitFile = os.path.splitext(file.name)
    #getting imports    
    imports, classes = importsAndClass(file)

    nodeNames.add(str(filename))
    v = Vert(str(filename), counter,analyzer.total_complexity, imports)
    #creating vertex
    nodes[v.name] = v
    counter = counter + 1 
    net.add_node(v.id, label=v.name, size=v.size*2)

print("_________________________________")
for k, v in nodes.items():
    
    for i in v.edges:
        withPY = i + ".py"
        print(withPY)
        try:
            to = nodes[withPY].id 
            net.add_edge(v.id, to)
        except:
            print("could not add edge to:" + str(i))    
        


net.show("network.html")
```

Now, when i draw my graph, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRfhO.png), things are super bunched up on top of eachother.
So I wanted some way to avoid overlapping. After researching a bit, I found that I should probably add this line:

```
net.barnes_hut(overlap=1)
```

Which, I do. This results in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78XTS.png), which looks much nicer, but now all of the sudden, all the labels on the nodes are gone!?.

Why is my labels gone? and how can I get both non-overlapping, and labels?
**Edit:**

I now tried this option:

```
net.force_atlas_2based(overlap= 1)
```

and this actually does what I want. The only problem now is that the nodes sometimes hit eachother, and start wiggling uncontrollably

Answer (score 3):

Try using option menu and play with different gravity features of `force_atlas_2based()` (i.e., `gravitationalConstant` and `centralGravity`).

You can have the option menu in your saved .html file:

```
# Graph construction ...
# ...
# Export to HTML file with physics manipulation options
net.show_buttons(filter_=["physics"])
net.show("graph_test.html")
```